# Why My App keep force closing when i click the item?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i don't know why My App keep force closing when i click an item with RecyclerView, it should be move to the DetailActivity when when i click the item.

They don't give me an error when i run the App, here is my code..

### MainActivity.kt

```
package me.wildan.nutspedia

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import me.wildan.nutspedia.Nuts
import me.wildan.nutspedia.NutsData
import me.wildan.nutspedia.ListViewAdapter

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var rvNuts: RecyclerView
    private var list: ArrayList<Nuts> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rvNuts = findViewById(R.id.rv_nuts)
        rvNuts.setHasFixedSize(true)

        list.addAll(NutsData.listData)
        showRecyclerListView()
    }

    private fun moveToDetail(nuts: Nuts) {
        val moveIntent = Intent(this,DetailActivity::class.java)
        moveIntent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, nuts.name)
        moveIntent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO, nuts.photo)
        moveIntent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DESC, nuts.desc)
        startActivity(moveIntent)
    }

    private fun showRecyclerListView() {
        val listViewNutsAdapter = ListViewAdapter(list)

        rvNuts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvNuts.adapter = listViewNutsAdapter

        listViewNutsAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : ListViewAdapter.OnItemClickCallback{
            override fun onItemClicked(item : Nuts) {
                moveToDetail(item)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### ListViewAdapter.kt

```
package me.wildan.nutspedia

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions

class ListViewAdapter(private val listNuts: ArrayList<Nuts>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ListViewHolder>(){
    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback : OnItemClickCallback

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(item : Nuts)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback){
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }

    inner class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo)
        var tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
        var tvDesc: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_detail)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ListViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_listview_nuts, viewGroup, false)
        return ListViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val nuts = listNuts[position]

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(nuts.photo)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(350, 350))
            .into(holder.imgPhoto)

        holder.tvName.text = nuts.name
        holder.tvDesc.text = nuts.desc

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(listNuts[holder.adapterPosition]) }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listNuts.size
    }
}
```

### DetailActivity.kt

```
package me.wildan.nutspedia

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var ivImgReceived : ImageView
    private lateinit var tvNameReceived : TextView
    private lateinit var tvDescReceived : TextView

    private var title : String = "Detail Menu"

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_DESC = "extra_desc"
        const val EXTRA_NAME = "extra_name"
        const val EXTRA_PHOTO = "extra_photo"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
        setActionBarTitle(title)

        ivImgReceived = findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo)
        tvNameReceived = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
        tvDescReceived = findViewById(R.id.tv_item_detail)

        val nutsPhoto = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO,0)
        val nutsName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME)
        val nutsDesc = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DESC)

        ivImgReceived.setImageResource(nutsPhoto)
        tvNameReceived.text = nutsName
        tvDescReceived.text = nutsDesc

    }

    private fun setActionBarTitle(title: String) {
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.title = title
    }

}
```

### Here is the log

[image]
[image]

Please tell me what to do. I'll appreciate it, thanks...

Comment: Put position instead of holder.adapterPosition in onBindViewHolder

Comment: Hi @TusharLathiya , thanks for the answer, i put position just like you said. But still didn't work, it keep force closing :(

Comment: Can you attach the log so we can see where its giving exception

Comment: @M.BilalAsif Hi, please take a look to my question, i just attach the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `DetailActivity.class` name and register it in AndroidManifest.xml file

like this inside application tag

```
<activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the `holder.adapterPosition` to the `position`.

I did not see an assignment for `holder.adapterPosition` one in your code. check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i change it to position. But still didn't work, it keep force closing the app when i click the item

Comment: can you share your logs that show in the Logcat?

Comment: Hi, please take a look to my question, i just attach the log